# Can anyone recommend a fast method to compute eigenvalues for large size matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I know only one way to compute eigenvalues by using characteristic polynomial, but for big sizes it takes long time to compute. Can anyone recommend other methods for computing eigenvalues for large size matrices?

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical approach?

Comment: This is a very broad topic and the answer depends on the type of the matrix. Start by reading the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm.

Comment: @caverac any way numerical approach

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank for the link :)

Comment: It all depends on your matrix. there are methods for sparse matrices and other for different type of matrices. Then there is the question "do you want all the eigenvalues or some of  them".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm